# VSCode add snippet on next line below selection

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to move the cursor on to the next line? Basically I want to select a variable, type my shortcode and have it console log it on a new line. So

`var foo = 'bar';`

becomes

```
var foo = 'bar';
console.log("foo", foo);
```

So far I've got

```
"Console log with variables": {
        "prefix": "cll",
        "body": ["$TM_SELECTED_TEXT",
            "console.log(\"$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\", $TM_SELECTED_TEXT);"],
        "description": "Console log from within js"
    },
```

but it overwrites the variable (obviously)

Comment: you have to insert the snippet with a key binding

Comment: how can there be 2 users with the id `Mark`

Comment: @rioV8 He is clearly an impostor! - from The Real Mark(TM)

Comment: Imposter???? You've seen my code then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do it in two steps - which I think you are trying to avoid - you could use this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "console.log (\"$CLIPBOARD\", $CLIPBOARD);"
  }
}
```

which requires you to copy the variable first and then move down a line, and then trigger the keybinding (or it could just be a snippet with no keybinding).

---

To do it in one step:

Here is a solution using an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview),.  Put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+i",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",     // copy it first
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter"          // insert a blank line below
    ],
    "replace": "console.log (\"${CLIPBOARD}\", ${CLIPBOARD});"
  }
}
```

Comment: What a great extension!! Would have been nice to do it with snippets, but that is still a great solution