# VS Code how to create custom shortcut / snippet?

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, shortcut, code-snippets

What is the simpliest way to create custom shortcuts for methods I'm using everydays?
Like `dd()` `Log::info()` or `console.log()`.

Let me explain exactly what behavior I want for my shortcut:

1. I want to select my variable
2. Press keyboard shorcut
3. Break a line
4. Passt the code I want with the selected variable

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734371/vscode-user-snippet-move-cursor/71742462#71742462 - the same question.  There is no easy way to do this, so I included that functionality in an extension.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606835/836330 for a macro solution if you don't mind having the new value on the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you @Mark I came with the solution with multi-command, works great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, thanks to @Mark in comments, related to this thread : [How can I insert a snippet on a new line with vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599250/how-can-i-insert-a-snippet-on-a-new-line-with-vscode/53606835#53606835)

1. Install Multi-command VSCode extension
2. Open the settings of the extension and click on `Edit in settings.json`
   [image]
3. Implement your shortcut code (e.g `console.log()`)

   ```
    "multiCommand.commands": [

        {
            "command": "multiCommand.console.log",

            "sequence": [
                "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
                "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
                {
                "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
                "args": {
                    "snippet": "console.log(\"$CLIPBOARD: \", $$CLIPBOARD)\n$0"
                }
                },
            ]
        },
   ```
4. Then in VSCode go to Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts, open keybindings.json
   [image: keybindings.json location]
5. Add the path binding command

   ```
   // (new version)
   {
       "key": "ctrl+1", 
       "command": "multiCommand.console.log" 
   }

   // (old version)
   {
       "key": "ctrl+1",
       "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
       "args": { "command": "multiCommand.console.log" }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can probably just use `$0` to show where your cursor will end and use `\n` to insert a line break.

However, I'm not entirely sure if this works when creating a snippet from the Keyboard Shortcut file, but it works from the snippet file so I'm assuming it'll work here.

Comment: in keybindings it will replace the text I selected and break my line. I found the solution with the multi-command extension, works well for what I needed and easier to implement

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. I misunderstood the question. Glad you found a solution!